# What CSS3 features does Internet Explorer 8 support?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, css

I was trying to find a definitive article on the IE blog but found nothing. I'm building an internal website where the majority of users are using Safari 4 and Firefox 3. Some PC users are using IE8 so I'd like to know what I should watch out for when I'm using CSS3.

Comment: Your question could be phrased as "What parts of CSS3 released in 2012 does a browser that was released in 2009 support?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[css3.info](http://www.css3.info/modules/) provides an authoratative overview of the implementation statuses of various modules in different browsers. Most modules are in fact not implemented by any mainstream module, but you can view the compatibility tables for certain modules, which provide detailed information.

Answer (score 7):

I mostly rely on [Wikipedia's article comparing CSS layout engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets)). It's a lot more comprehensive than any of the other links posted so far.

Basically, IE8 doesn't support any CSS3, except for some selectors and some properties that originated at Microsoft to begin with.

Answer (score 6):

One method to get CSS3 to work with IE is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com).

Their you get `PIE.htc` file which enables css3 behavior in your IE browser

Comment: PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features

Comment: I've personally found this post tremendously useful as I hadn't heard of CSS3Pie before.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for the record, I would also recommend http://caniuse.com/. You can easily look up the support for any given feature.

Also, regarding CSS3Pie, I would encourage caution. There are some really specific requirements regarding how you can implement it that make it difficult to maintain. For example:

- The path to PIE.htc must be relative to the html page and not the css file where it is linked.
- If you use an absolute path, it must be on the same domain.

See here: http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/

Answer (score 0):

The [compatibility master table](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) on [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/) lists IE8's CSS3 support as "minimal" when behaving as IE7, and "incomplete" when behaving as IE8. For an extremely detailed breakdown of exactly what is supported and what isn't, see Quirksmode's excellent [CSS browser compatiblity chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CaniUse](http://caniuse.com/#cats=CSS), [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), [FindmebyIP to check what your client browser support](http://fmbip.com/) and [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) 
 for email compatibility