# Animated tooltips with CSS3

Tags: css, animation, internet-explorer-8

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/01/how-to-create-animated-tooltips-with-css3/

This is an excellent instruction but does not work with IE8... 
Is it possible that the animation does not showing in IE 8? 
Some code to stop animation but that displays the icons.
Please, can someone help?

Demo: 
http://tympanus.net/TipsTricks/CSS3Tooltips/

Comment: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/01/how-to-create-animated-tooltips-with-css3/comment-page-3/#comment-419872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 features will not work in IE8, check this [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615745/what-css3-features-does-internet-explorer-8-support).

Therefore you should try something works in IE8.   Or write css only IE8 using conditional comments.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
//apply css
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Not succeeded... I hide animation for all browsers... Thanks for suggestion.